# c# - AutoMapper: how to copy fields from 2 different sources into 1 destination

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have a flat file with a bunch of records, let's say it's a sequence of 2 record types

--- Record1: ID;NAME;SURNAME
--- Record2: AGE;SEX;

Let's call R1 the class representing Record1 and R2 the class representing Record2
In this moment I have an array of R1 and another array of R2
If I have a POCO called Subject that has 5 fields, named exactly as the union of the fields of R1 and R2, how do I configure AutoMapper to do the magic for   me?

Now I'm trying this:

`var subjects = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<R1>, List<Subject>>(arrayOfR1s);
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<R2>, List<Subject>>(arrayOfR2s, subjects);`

After the first mapping, I get an array of Subjects, in every element of the array the fields ID, SURNAME, NAME are correctly filled with values. AGE and SEX are left to NULL as expected.
But after the second mapping, all the fields from R1 (ID, NAME, SURNAME) are initialized to NULL and I only get fields from R2 (AGE and SEX).

How do I get the complete union of the fields?
Can someone point me to the right approach?

Comment: >In this moment I have an array of R1 and another array of R2

The arrays have the same number of elements? First R1 element corresponds to the first R2 element and so on?

Comment: >But after the second mapping, all the fields from R1 are initialized.
Isn't it good? Seems like R1 fields should be already initailized after first call. Did you want to say 'only R1'?

Comment: @Serge Yes, so subjects[0] would be the union of the fields of R1[0] and R2[0]

Comment: @KolA after first mapping, subjects[] has the three feields ID, NAME, SURNAME filled with values, AGE and SEX are NUll. after the second mapping, ID,NAME,SURNAME are NULL and AGE,SEX are filled with values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the straightforward dynamic mapping of *joined* (anonymously typed) objects?

```
Record1[] firstRecords = new[]
    {
        new Record1
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "John", Surname = "Doe"
            },
        new Record1
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Jane", Surname = "Roe"
            }
    };

Record2[] secondRecords = new[]
    {
        new Record2 { Age = 20, Sex = Sex.Male },
        new Record2 { Age = 20, Sex = Sex.Female }
    };

var subjects = firstRecords
    .Select((first, index) =>
        {
            var second = secondRecords[index];
            var r = new
                {
                    ID = first.ID,
                    Name = first.Name,
                    Surname = first.Surname,
                    Age = second.Age,
                    Sex = second.Sex
                };
            return Mapper.DynamicMap<Subject>(r);
        })
    .ToArray();
```

By the way, you can map these object without using AutoMapper, but using LINQ `Select()`.

```
var subjects = firstRecords
    .Select((first, index) =>
        {
            var second = secondRecords[index];
            var r = new Subject
                {
                    ID = first.ID,
                    Name = first.Name,
                    Surname = first.Surname,
                    Age = second.Age,
                    Sex = second.Sex
                };
            return r;
        })
    .ToArray();
```

### Update

If you need to copy a lot of properties, please take a look at the [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/). `InjectFrom()` FTW!

```
var subjects = firstRecords
.Select((first, index) =>
    {
        var second = secondRecords[index];
        var r = new Subject();
        r.InjectFrom(first).InjectFrom(second);
        return r;
    })
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I really like your suggestions, very much appreciated. I have a problem, tho... My example was simple enought to give you the idea of the problem, but my R1 and R2 have more than 20 properites each, I would like to avoid writing them all in the anonymous type definition.... that's why I'm using AutoMapper. But I don't know if there is a solution here...

Comment: @Genesio, okay, I see the point. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I am trying Value Injecter. Your solution would be wonderful if only my R1, R2 and Subject classes were exposing values as Properties. Unfortunately I cannot use properties, but only fields (a restriction from using FileHelpers library). I will check if I can write a custom Injection enging. thank you very much, your help is really appreciated